# Why do email drop-downs show "email protected"

Tags: email

Whether when selecting a from email address in CiviMail (or Civi regular email), or selecting (the email of) an existing user in Drupal Webform_CiviCRM, the email will sometimes be hidden and the message "email protected" will be displayed instead. 
It seems to happen only when I access the site with a https URL. When I access the site using http, I can see the email.
This has been the case on all Civi versions with Drupal 7. Same thing when logged in as user 1

What causes this and how do we get rid of it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Yossi - I have never seen this. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I updated the question with screenshots and more details

Comment: can you add screenshot for  this in civimail and just standard mail? webform may have other mysteries involved

Comment: and are you sure you don't have some customisation in place?

Comment: or are you using anything like CloudFlare which might be doing some obfuscation?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, the zoomed-in image is from Civi email. I am using Cloudflare. Can that be causing this?

Comment: I searched through the latest codebase and the phrase "email protected" does not appear at any point. Hence it is unlikely CiviCRM. CloudFlare does do this via ScrapeShield, good digging Pete. See: https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-scrapeshield-discover-defend-dete/ @petednz-fuzion - I'll let you write the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is something external to civicrm. Services like CloudFlare can cause email addressed to be 'protected'  and the fact you are saying this happens on https but not http seems to be another pointer in that direction.

You might want to consider this article: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation- or the one suggested by Michael https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-scrapeshield-discover-defend-dete/